# Runtime Query in Oracle store procedures not returning proper result

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, procedure

This is first my stint with procedure and I am trying to execute below oracle procedure but facing some issue. Any inputs on this would be really helpful:

Issue:-----
I have a select query that returns two values:

```
    src_Columns contains:
        ID_ELEMENT
        ID_ELEMENT_SA
```

Now, When I am trying to travesre a select-query(single column) result using "For Loop", I am not getting the values of the column rather I am getting its name only.

```
FOR columnItem IN (SELECT src_Columns FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE)
           LOOP
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Columns 3: ' || columnItem.src_Columns);
           query_test:=  'insert into ' || destination_Table || '(NAME,' || dest_Columns_Value || ') VALUES( ''' || src_name_Value || ''',''' || columnItem.dummyValue || ''')';
           dbms_output.put_line('query_test:' || query_test);
           execute immediate query_test;
           END LOOP;
```

I mean the test query generated is following when i use variable name(src_columns):

```
insert into ATT_WTPART(NAME,STRINGVALUE) VALUES( 'ID_ELEMENT_SA','ID_ELEMENT_SA')
```

whereas if I use ID_ELEMENT_SA instead of src_Columns in FOR LOOP

```
FOR columnItem IN (SELECT ID_ELEMENT FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE)
```

then I get proper values that are desired like

```
insert into ATT_WTPART(NAME,STRINGVALUE) VALUES( 'ID_ELEMENT_SA','ID05')
```

How can I make sure that I get the values even when I am using the variable name instead of any hard-coding

Below is the Complete Procedure:-------------

```
 create or replace 
PROCEDURE ELEM90_Lnk_Elem_ATT_WTPART_MK
AS
CURSOR targ_dest_relation IS
    SELECT sourcecolumn  FROM mapping where destinationtable='ATT_WTPART';
    BEGIN
DECLARE 

dest_Columns varchar2(1000);
src_Columns varchar2(1000); 
src_Type varchar2(1000);
destination_Table varchar2(1000) := 'ATT_WTPART';
source_Table varchar2(1000) := 'ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE';
query_test varchar2(1000);
query_test2 varchar2(1000);
src_name varchar2(255);
src_Type_Value varchar2(255);
dest_Columns_Value varchar2(255);
src_name_Value varchar2(255);
for_query varchar2(1000);
for_query_data varchar2(1000);
dummyValue varchar2(1000); 

BEGIN

    FOR rec IN targ_dest_relation loop
           dbms_output.put_line('destination_Table: ' || destination_Table);
           dbms_output.put_line('source_Table: ' || source_Table);

           src_Columns :=  rec.sourcecolumn;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Columns: ' || src_Columns);

           src_Type := 'select data_type from user_tab_columns where table_name ='''||source_Table||'''and column_name='''|| src_Columns ||'''';
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Type: ' || src_Type);

           execute immediate src_Type INTO src_Type_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Type_Value: ' || src_Type_Value);

           dest_Columns := 'select DEST_COLUMN from ATT_PART_MAPPING where SOURCETYPE='''|| src_Type_Value || '''';
           dbms_output.put_line('dest_Columns: '  || dest_Columns);

           execute immediate dest_Columns INTO dest_Columns_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('dest_Columns_Value: ' || dest_Columns_Value);

           src_name := 'select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name ='''|| source_Table ||'''  and column_name= ''' || src_Columns || '''';
           dbms_output.put_line('src_name: ' || src_name);

           execute immediate src_name INTO src_name_Value;
           dbms_output.put_line('src_name_Value: ' || src_name_Value);

           FOR columnItem IN (SELECT src_Columns FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE)
           LOOP
           dbms_output.put_line('src_Columns 3: ' || columnItem.src_Columns);
           query_test:=  'insert into ' || destination_Table || '(NAME,' || dest_Columns_Value || ') VALUES( ''' || src_name_Value || ''',''' || columnItem.dummyValue || ''')';
           dbms_output.put_line('query_test:' || query_test);
           execute immediate query_test;
           END LOOP;

    END loop;  
END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the line

```
FOR columnItem IN (SELECT src_Columns FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE)
```

is that `src_Columns` is a local variable.  As a result, you end up selecting the same value for each row in `ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE`.

If you want the value of the local variable to be used as a column name in the query, you must use dynamic SQL instead.  Try replacing `FOR columnItem ... LOOP ... END LOOP` with the following:

```
           OPEN curs FOR 'SELECT ' || src_Columns || ' FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE';
           LOOP
             FETCH curs INTO column_value;
             EXIT WHEN curs%NOTFOUND;
             dbms_output.put_line('src_Columns 3: ' || column_value);
             query_test:=  'insert into ' || destination_Table || '(NAME,' || dest_Columns_Value || ') VALUES( ''' || src_name_Value || ''',''' || column_value || ''')';
             dbms_output.put_line('query_test:' || query_test);
             execute immediate query_test;
           END LOOP;

           CLOSE curs;
```

You will need to declare the following extra variables:

```
curs         SYS_REFCURSOR;
column_value VARCHAR2(4000);
```

---

However, in truth it would probably be better to remove the loop entirely.  You can replace it with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` statement instead, such as the following:

```
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || destination_Table || ' (NAME,' ||
           dest_Columns_Value || ') SELECT :name,' || src_Columns || 
           ' FROM ELEM90_LNK_ELEM_BOSE' USING src_name_Value;
```

This also gets rid of the need for the two local variables `curs` and `column_value`, and is also likely to be considerably faster, as there's no need to parse dynamic SQL once for each row in the destination table.

Comment: Thnks for your suggestion...It worked like rocket :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it working better if you try this one:

```
query_test:=  'insert into ' || destination_Table || 
   '(NAME,'||dest_Columns_Value||') VALUES (:p1, :p2)';
execute immediate query_test USING src_name_Value, columnItem.dummyValue;
```

At least it should have a positive impact on performance.

Comment: It is still behaving as earlier.